# How to manipulate DOM on Fancybox content?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to access on elements in DOM content loaded with Fancybox but it's impossible.

Here an example of my code :

```
<div id="content"><!-- content of my FancyBox !-->
   blabla 
  <div class="myelement">blabla hiding</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fancybox({
content : $('#content').html(),
afterLoad: function(){
  //do something with the element
  $('.myelement').hide();

}
);
</script>
```

Nothing happen on the content of my fancybox (The element isn't hiding).

Thank you all.

Comment: I have no error but nothing happens... because the fancybox load and **create** duplicate content from div#content.

Comment: What you want with the fancybox? Because your code is no-sense

Comment: I display a form on my fancybox, and i would like to control an input by using : $('.element').keyup(function(){ ..}); but this element isn't accessible

Comment: can you post all your code cut some parte to read well It

Comment: I just updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the bug !

If I want to manipulate DOM content added dynamically by the FancyBox, I have to use the callback "afterShow" :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$.fancybox({
content : $('#content').html(),
afterShow: function(){ //<====== FIX THE BUG !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  //do something with the element
  $('.myelement').hide();

}
);
</script>
```